# Procedimiento Contador de espacios

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo un procedimiento para contar los espacios en una cadena.
El problema viene que el sistema se traga el procedimiento pero al llamarla para que muestre el resultado se me cuelga y no encuentro el error.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS NUMEROSDEESPACIOS;

DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE NUMEROSDEESPACIOS(IN cadena TEXT, OUT mensaje TEXT)

BEGIN

     DECLARE resultado INTEGER DEFAULT -1;
     DECLARE caracteres INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE posicion INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE caracter CHAR(1) DEFAULT '';

     SET caracteres = CHARACTER_LENGTH(cadena);

          WHILE posicion < caracteres DO
               SET caracter = SUBSTRING(cadena, posicion, 1);
          IF caracter LIKE ' ' THEN
               SET posicion = posicion + 1;
          END IF;
               SET resultado = resultado +1;
          END WHILE;
     SET mensaje = CONCAT('Tiene ',resultado);
    END |

DELIMITER ;

CALL NUMEROSDEESPACIOS('paco paco ',@pro1);
SELECT  @pro1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se cuelga porque estas provocando un bucle infinito. Si prestas atención solo incrementes `posicion` si `caracter = ' '`, es decir para cualquier otro caso nunca incrementas `posicion`.

### Solución:

Hay varias cosas que corregir:

- No inicializar la variables en el `DECLARE`
- `posicion` debe empezar en `1` para que el `SUBSTRING` funcione
- `resultado` debe iniciar en `0` (*no en `-1`*)
- Por lo anterior el `WHILE` debe ser mientras `posicion <= caracteres`
- Si `caracter = ' '` entonces incrementamos `resultado` (*no `posicion`*)
- Antes del `END WHILE` incrementamos `posicion`

#### Ejemplo:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS NUMEROSDEESPACIOS;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE NUMEROSDEESPACIOS(IN cadena TEXT, OUT mensaje TEXT)

BEGIN

    DECLARE caracteres INTEGER;
    DECLARE resultado INTEGER;
    DECLARE posicion INTEGER;
    DECLARE caracter CHAR(1);

    SET caracteres = CHARACTER_LENGTH(cadena);
    SET resultado = 0;
    SET posicion = 1;
    SET mensaje = '';

    WHILE posicion <= caracteres DO
        SET caracter = SUBSTRING(cadena, posicion, 1);
        
        IF caracter = ' ' THEN
            SET resultado = resultado +1;
        END IF;
        SET posicion = posicion + 1;
        
    END WHILE;
    SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje, 'Tiene ',resultado);
    
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oZS7PSNkMPgaisXzar5CrP/0)</kbd>